# Grep not finding files when given them in a list

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file called `file_names_list.txt` which contains absolute file names, for example, the first line is: 
`~/Projects/project/src/files/file.mm`

I run a script to grep each of these files,

```
for file in $(cat file_names_list.txt); do 
        echo "doing file: $file"
        grep '[ \t]*if (.* = .*) {' $file | while read -r line ; do ...
```

and I get the output:

```
doing file: ~/Projects/project/src/files/file.mm
grep: ~/Projects/project/src/files/file.mm: No such file or directory
```

But if I go to the terminal and enter

`grep '[ \t]*if (.* = .*) {' ~/Projects/project/src/files/file.mm`

I get the proper grep output

What's the problem here? I'm out of ideas

Comment: It is the tilde `~` at the front.  That does not get translated because ion the order the shell does expansions.  There are ways around it, the simplest is to use `$HOME` instead (put it inside double quotes `"` instead of single).

Comment: Another possible solution is to add `eval file="$file"` before the `grep`, but `eval` is often frowned upon.  It gives an extra "scan" and expansion.

Comment: Note that a filename is absolute only if it begins with a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `~` character. That character gets expanded to your home directory when you use it in bash but in this case, it is just another character stored in the variable `$file`. To see the difference, try this:

```
file='~'
echo $file
echo ~
```

So now you have to either recreate the file `file_names_list.txt` or try to fix it, e.g. with `sed`:

```
sed -i -e "s|^~/|$HOME/|" file_names_list.txt
```

Also note that it would be prefereable to use a while loop instead of a for loop:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
    # write your code here
done < file_names_list.txt
```

Comment: I edited the files list to replace `~` with `$HOME`  and I'm getting `$HOME/Projects/....` DNE. There are no single quotes anywhere, so I don't know why it's not expanding

Comment: I fixed it by using the absolute paths in the list of files. Why is a while loop better than a or loop in this case?

Comment: The while loop (as I wrote it), handles whitespace characters better. Also, it processes the file one line a time instead of loading the entire file in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your script like this:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
   grep '[ \t]*if .* = .* {' "${f/#\~/\$HOME}"
done < file_names_list.txt
```

Since `~` cannot be stored in a variable and expanded we are replacing starting `~` by `$HOME` in each line in this BASH expression: `"${f/#\~/\$HOME}"`

Comment: What if a name doesn't begin with `~`?